# Расшифровать md5 в pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, хеширование, md5

Прошу помочь по шифрованию/дешифрованию в md5 в оракле.

Имеются строки в таблице зашифрованные в MD5 - необходимо их привести в читабельный вид.

Например, если зашифровать такую строку:

```
DECLARE
TESTSTRING VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
TESTSTRING := DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5(INPUT => UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('1122334455'));
END;
```

Как полученный хэш расшифровать обратно в строку?

Comment: Ключевое слово тут "хеш", а хеш, это не шифрование, он не обратим по своей природе. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хеш невозможно расшифровать. Это сродни задаче:

> Сумма слагаемых: 12345. Найдите слагаемые по их сумме.

Для "взлома" хешей применяют метод грубой силы (`brute force attack`). Это когда перебором подбирают строки, хешируют их и сравнивают этот хеш с тем , который хотят взломать. При совпадении есть шанс, что это и была исходная строка.

**NOTE:** [могут быть другие строки / комбинации, дающие точно такой же хеш](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1434/are-there-two-known-strings-which-have-the-same-md5-hash-value)

Также можно использовать атаку по словарю - если у нас есть словарь возможных строк (например известных / украденных паролей), то мы опять же пробегаем по словарю и сравниваем хеши с заданным.

Comment: *Для "взлома" хешей* Лучше использовать всё же аккуратный термин "поиск коллизии" - во-первых, он точно отражает суть происходящего, во-вторых, снимает налёт криминальности с действия, которое вполне может быть легитимным.

Comment: @Akina, не нравится мне такой термин...)

Comment: А если мне известны например первые и последние 2 цифры, есть ли примеры подобных брутфорсов?

Comment: @Dilitand брутфорс - это тупой подбор. А подбирать все символы или только с третьего по шестой - какая в сущности разница? просто работы меньше.

Comment: *не нравится мне такой термин* Ну нет так нет, моё дело предложить...

Comment: @Dilitand, как сказал __Akina__, принцип остается тем же, но скорость перебора значительно ускоряется

Comment: Короче говоря, я так понял если нет словаря, с которым можно осуществить сравнение, то "угадать" его не получиться...

Comment: @Dilitand,подобрать можно, если количество вариантов соответствует вашим доступным ресурсам